# How do you resolve a TypeError concerning watchID and navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition?

Tags: javascript, react-native, geolocation, react-navigation

The error im getting is:

## TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.geoLocation.watchPosition'>

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import {Container, Header, Button, Body, Icon, Content, Item, Form, Input } from 'native-base';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = height
const SCREEN_WIDTH = width
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.922
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO

export default class DriverMapScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      initialPosition: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
        latitudeDelta: 0,
        longitudeDelta: 0
      },
      markerPosition: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0
      }
    }
  }

  watchID: ?number = null

  componentDidMount() {
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      let lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
      let long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

      let initialRegion = {
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: long,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta:LONGITUDE_DELTA
      }

    this.setState({initialPosition: initialRegion})
    this.setState({markerPosition: initialRegion})
  },
  (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
  {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000})

  watchID = navigator.geoLocation.watchPosition((position) => {
    let lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
    let long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

    let lastRegion = {
      latitude: lat,
      longitude: long,
      longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
      latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA
    }

    this.setState({initialPosition: lastRegion})
    this.setState({markerPosition: lastRegion})
  })
}

  componentWillUnmount() {
    navigator.geoLocation.clearWatch(this.watchID)
  }


  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView style={styles.map}
          region={this.state.initialPosition}
          loadingEnabled={true}
          loadingIndicatorColor={'#3a9def'}
        >

          <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={this.state.markerPosition}
            title={"title"}
            description={"description"}
          >
              <View style={styles.radius}>
                <View style={styles.marker} />
              </View>
          </MapView.Marker>
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0
  },
  radius: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    borderRadius: 50 / 2,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 122, 255, 0.1)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 122, 255, 0.3)',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  marker: {
    height: 20,
    width: 20,
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 20 / 2,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    backgroundColor: '#007AFF'
  }
})
```

The error designates this line as the origin of the error:

```
watchID: ?number = null
```

Do you guys have any idea what my issue is? The code along i watched resulted in working code and I'm just not quite sure why my watchID evaluates to undefined. Does this problem come from lack of declaring watchID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

1. You appear to be using both a `getCurrentPosition` and a `watchCurrentPosition`. I would select one.
2. Your `getCurrentPosition` is inside of `componentDidMount`, while your `watchCurrentPosition` is not inside any method. For this reason, it's likely being interpreted as an ES6 class property: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/. If you don't have the linked Babel plugin setup, it won't be able to interpret your syntax.
3. Similarly, `watchID` is being interpreted as an ES6 class property (or rather, likely not being interpreted at all). Without the above plugin, you can't declare variables outside of methods - and when you do they are properties on the class, not methods.

What you would want to do instead is declare `this.watchID` inside of `componentDidMount`. Then, you should have access to it from other methods. Take a look at [this Expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/SJb5ZGMd-) - I think it should accomplish what you want.

Comment: thanks for the reply, Parker!

1) what's the difference between getCurrentPosition and watchCurrentPosition? Which would you suggest using here to track a mobile users location?

2) This was a formatting error on my part. the watchCurrentPosition was indeed inside of componentDidMount.

3) I removed watchID that was outside of the componentDidMount method and declared it at the start of componentDidMount method. I also npm installed babel-plugin-transform-class-properties but I'm still getting the same error. The error stack indicates the error is located right before componentDidMount

Comment: Hey @aglaze! 1) getCurrentPosition will get the user's position a single time, but will not update the position as a user moves. watchCurrentPosition will continually watch the user's position and update as the user moves. I think you'd want watchCurrentPosition if you want to keep tracking on as they move. 2) No worries, if possible could you create an Expo snack: https://snack.expo.io with your current code for the above file. 3) Even if you `npm install`, you'd need to make sure your `.babelrc` file is configured properly. Could you add your `.babelrc` to the original post?

Comment: Another important thing to ask - are you using `typescript`? If not, the `watchID: ?number = null` syntax would likely error.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Parker. Really appreciate it.


sounds like watchCurrentPosition is exactly what i need. 

2) Here is the snack expo: https://snack.expo.io/ryb4dWJGf

Theres a few errors for unused variables and for navigator not being defined(how is this not defined?)

Comment: 3) I'm not using typescript ( i dont think ). i got this code from a codealong and the programmer didn't mention typescript, babel, or anything like that. All he said was declare watchID as such. Could you provide any guidance on whether or not I should continue down this route with babel, or if there is another way I can declare it? Here is the .babelrc file:

{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo", "flow"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
    }
  }
}

Comment: Ok, that line `watchID: ?number = null` is providing a type annotation of `number` to `watchID`. If you don't have TS enabled, it'll throw an error. Remove that from your current code and let me know how that works.